# Making data array from Model query

Tags: php, laravel

I was wondering how to obtain just a an array of data from one of my Models.
So far I haven't been able to. If I do this on tinker:

```
$payout = Minner::select('est_month_payment')->get();
```

I got this:

```
>>> $payout = Minner::select('est_month_payment')->get();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4394
     all: [
       App\Models\Minner {#4304
         est_month_payment: 0.00868224,
       },
       App\Models\Minner {#4239
         est_month_payment: 0.00868224,
       },
       App\Models\Minner {#4459
         est_month_payment: 0.00868224,
       },
       App\Models\Minner {#4468
         est_month_payment: 0.00868224,
       },
       App\Models\Minner {#4469
         est_month_payment: 0.00868224,
       },
       App\Models\Minner {#4470
         est_month_payment: 0.00868224,
       },
       App\Models\Minner {#4471
         est_month_payment: 0.00868224,
       },
       App\Models\Minner {#4474
         est_month_payment: 0.00945744,
       },
     ],
   }
>>>
```

Even is I use toArray() at the end I got this:

```
>>> $payout = Minner::select('est_month_payment')->get()->toArray();
=> [
     [
       "est_month_payment" => 0.00868224,
     ],
     [
       "est_month_payment" => 0.00868224,
     ],
     [
       "est_month_payment" => 0.00868224,
     ],
     [
       "est_month_payment" => 0.00868224,
     ],
     [
       "est_month_payment" => 0.00868224,
     ],
     [
       "est_month_payment" => 0.00868224,
     ],
     [
       "est_month_payment" => 0.00868224,
     ],
     [
       "est_month_payment" => 0.00945744,
     ],
   ]
>>>
```

But what I need is to have an array that looks like this:

```
$payout=[
            '0.00868224',
            '0.00868224',
            '0.00868224',
            '0.00868224',
            '0.00868224',
            '0.00868224',
            '0.00945744',
        ];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pluck`

```
$payout = Minner::pluck('est_month_payment')->toArray();
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

Comment: Wonderful thanks. That was exactly what I need it.